# Gitlab 500 Error: PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I'm running Gitlab-CE v8.11.3-ce.1

My house lost power, and so that abruptly shut down my Gitlab server. I power it back on, and it gives me a 500 error.
When I do `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, I'm getting this in the log:

```
[execute] psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
            Is the server running locally and accepting
            connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here's my database section of `gitlab.rb`:

```
# gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
# gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = "unicode"
# gitlab_rails['db_collation'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabhq_production"
# gitlab_rails['db_pool'] = 10
# gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
# gitlab_rails['db_password'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['db_host'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
# gitlab_rails['db_socket'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['db_sslmode'] = nil
# gitlab_rails['db_sslrootcert'] = nil
```

I didn't change any host or anything. Help.

Comment: Well, is your database running and accepting connections? The error message tells you what to do and noone here can help you with that.

Comment: @JakubKania yes, postgresql is running, as proven by `ps aux | grep postgresql`

Comment: And have you verified that you can connect to it using the socket? It seems that due to lack of db_host configured it's going for the socket rather than port.

Comment: @JakubKania How would I verify that I can connect to it via the socket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @twk3 for solving my question!
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1637

Solution:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
sudo systemctl stop gitlab-runsvdir.service
ps aux | grep postgre (check if there are any postgres processes; shouldn't be)
sudo rm /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid
sudo systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir.service
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

And it works!

Comment: I have the same error but there is no such file `/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid`

Comment: if there is no pid, go to the next step